# Why functions in module are not passed back to the main process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I need to load untrusted modules, written by third parties. I'm using `vm` for the sandbox and I was thinking to use `threads` (from npm: [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/threads)) in order to load the module asynchronously and avoid blocking code.

I have stripped down the code to the minimum, because I'm stuck and I dont' understand if what I'm trying to achieve is impossible or it's just me messing with scopes.

Here is a dummy module:

```
exports.dummy = function () {
    console.log('Dummy');
};

exports.val = 5;
```

And here is a module where I try to load this dummy module using threads:

```
var spawn = require('threads').spawn;

var mod;
var other;

var t = spawn(function (input, done) {
    var m = require(input.dir + '/dummyMod');
    done({m: m, other: 'hey'})
});

t.send({dir: __dirname}).on('message', function (result) {
    mod = result.m;
    other = result.other;
    console.log(mod);
    console.log(other);
    t.kill();
});
```

The logged output is:

```
{ val: 5 }
hey
```

As you can see, the function in the dummy module has been skipped. If I try to load the module in the main process and log it, then the function is, of course, part of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly serialize and deserialize the function. `JSON.stringify` ignores functions, probably because json is a format for storing data, not scripts.

Serialize the function by calling `toString()` on it. Then you can send it along as a string.

`done({m: m.toString(), other: 'hey'})`

Converting m to a string will give you something like this:

`"function m(){console.log(\'called m()\')}"`

On the receiving end, you will need to deserialize the function.

`var m = new Function("return " + result.m)()`

Comment: This way I lose the function scope. So, for example, if `dummy` was supposed to return `val` it won't find `val` in its scope.

Comment: Yes, you will lose scope. If that is a concern, then why not load the module with require() as usual? Can't that be done from within a thread?

Comment: I need to call the methods exported by that module in my main process. Nevertheless, the module is untrusted and if it loops during the loading process, it will block the execution. That's why I was thinking to load it in a child process and pass it back to the main process once the require ends.

Comment: I don't see why you can't include everything you need to run in the child process. Seems like running untrusted code in the main process would defeat the purpose of sandboxing. Anyway, I believe I answered the question of why functions aren't passed to the thread. Please consider accepting